# MaterialUI - Changing the color Textfield on focus

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change the color of the label text in Textfield but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
<TextField
    value={value}
    key={name}
    label={label}
    id={id}
    name={name}
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true,
      FormLabelClasses: {
        'root': {
          '&:focused': {
            color: 'white'
          }
        },
        focused: 'true'
      }
    }}
  />
```

Can someone give me a pointer on what I'm doing wrong here?

I've also tried using the `MuiThemeProvider` but can't seem to figure that one out either:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiFormLabel: {
      focused: true,
      root: {
        '&.focused': {
          color: 'white'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

How can I change the color of the Label? In this photo, I want the "Notes" to match the color of the underline

Thanks for your help!
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tim!
Here is the snippet that should help you.

```js
const {
  TextField,
  createMuiTheme,
  MuiThemeProvider,
  CssBaseline,
} = window['material-ui'];

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiFormLabel: {
      root: {
        "&$focused": {
          color: "tomato",
          fontWeight: "bold"
        }
      }, 
      
      focused: {}
    }
  }
});

class Index extends React.Component {  
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div>
          <CssBaseline />
          <TextField label="Text field" InputLabelProps={{shrink:true}} />
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This solved it :-) Seems like I was a bit off and need to do more reading into using `$`. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone else like me who didn't understand the answer, read the section on $rulename at https://material-ui.com/customization/components/

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks it is an obscene amount of time, code and energy to change the color of a font?

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing it without the override is to have:

```
const textStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& .Mui-focused": {
      color: "tomato", 
      fontWeight: "bold"
    },
});

class Index extends React.Component {  
  const TextClass = textStyles()
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div>
          <CssBaseline />
          <TextField className={textStyles.root} label="Text field" InputLabelProps={{shrink:true}} />
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

for v5 of @mui this code works

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiInputLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          "&.Mui-focused": {
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
          },
        },
      }
    },
    MuiTextField: {
      defaultProps: {
        variant: 'standard',
      },
    },
  },
```